# A method that is supposed to print all values of an array only returns nulls.

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have a constructor below where it reads from a text file and takes each line and assigns it to a section in the multi-dimensional array.

```
public ValueToArray(int rowsI, int columnsI, File fileLocationI){

        int i;
        int j;

        InputStream fileInputStream;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String line;

        rows = rowsI;
        columns = columnsI;
        count = 0;
        fileLocation = fileLocationI;
        array = new String[rows][columns];

        try{

            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){ // iterate through row
                for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){ // iterate through column
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){ // while the next line is not null
                        array[i][j] = line; // assign i-th j-th index as line (the input)
                        // System.out.println(array[i][j]);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I also wrote a method that prints out all values of the array:

```
    public void returnArray(){
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){ // iterate through row
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){ // iterate through column
                System.out.println(array[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my issue:

If I have `System.out.println(array[i][j]);` inside the while-loop of my constructor, I am able to print out all values, however, my `returnArray()` method only returns nulls after the first index, i.e.

```
0,0,0
null
null
null
null
null
```

I was wondering what issue it is I have with my method, or even my constructor, that's causing the `nulls`? I don't seem to be getting any errors within my IDE.

Comment: Is there only one line in your input file?

Comment: No exceptions are being reported. What is a scope issue and how can I fix it in the context of my code? I never knew that could be an issue with printing out values of an array.

Comment: @rgettman There's 1302 lines total. My `count()` method that "counts" how many lines there are in the text file reports 1302 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){ // iterate through row
            for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){ // iterate through column
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){ // while the next line is not null
                    array[i][j] = line; // assign i-th j-th index as line (the input)
                    // System.out.println(array[i][j]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
```

After entering the second for loop, the while loop will keep putting all the values and keep overwriting them to array[0][0]. So in the first iteration itself, your whole file is read and the last line in the file is the one that you would have at [0][0]. After that every iteration skips the while as there are no more lines in your file. hence, they all have null values.

Comment: Oh my.. That's so dumb of me.

Comment: Just add a break after every loop in the while loop. That should do the job

Comment: Can you explain to me what the break will do in the context of my code? From my understanding, you're `break`ing after you've completed the `array[i][j]` assignment?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage What i understand is you need to put 1 line in 1 row with each string a column. right ?

Answer (score 1):

so try this..

```
             for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){ // iterate through row
                for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){ // iterate through column
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){ // while the next line is not null
                        array[i][j] = line; // assign i-th j-th index as line (the input)
                        // System.out.println(array[i][j]);
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```